# Why are my TestRail test case ID's so high (e.g. over C14000) when we only have 1300 tests?

Tags: testing, testrail

Our test case ID's in TestRail are being created at a rate much higher than our actual test cases are being created. For example, this month when I create a new Case, it is assigned something like C14201, but just a few weeks ago it was assigning in the C12000 block. We definitely did not create 2000 test cases since then. Additionally, we only have about 1300 test cases total across all our suites.

Can someone help me understand what is happening and how I might stop it?

Comment: I think it's better to ask TR support about it. But in general - why would you care about it at all? Probably the int range is enough for any number of test cases you might create in your entire life :)

Answer (score 0):

In TestRail test case ID's are assigned sequentially under normal operating conditions and TestRrail doesn't supply any further configuration options.

If its is a big concern for you that case ID's having been unwittingly generated in your system , you can always reach out to the TestRail support to help you out.